# Error when reading huge file using R function in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have a text file that has 185405149 lines and a header.  I am reading in this file within this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N R_Job
#PBS -l walltime=4:00:00
#PBS -l vmem=20gb

module load R/4.2.1

cd filepath/

R --save -q -f script.R
```

Part of the script is below:

```
# import the gtex data 
gtex_data <- read.table("/filepath/file.txt", header=TRUE)
```

I get the error: Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.0 Gb
Execution halted.

It's got nothing to do with the directory/filepath. I suspect its to do with memory. Even after zipping the file e.g file.txt.gz and using the command:

```
gtex_data <- read.table(gzfile("/filepath/file.txt.gz"), header=TRUE)
```

It doesn't read the data.

I've tried with a smaller file e.g. reading the first 100 lines of file.txt and renaming it and loading it and it works fine.

I've even tried to increase vmem? Not sure what to do. I would be grateful for advice/help.

I've also checked the size of the file.

ls -lh file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 ... 107M Oct 26 16:50 file.txt

Comment: Fairly obviously, zipping the file and then unzipping it as it is read is unlikely to help.

Comment: If you have a file of 185,405,149 lines and 107,000,000 bytes then the average length of each line is 0.58 bytes (including the one-byte newline). So you are measuring something wrong. Your line count means an average of 11 bytes per line would break that 2GB limit (whatever is imposing that limit -- presumably gtex_data, but the error message should contain that information.).